# Computing the clustering coefficient

Tags: algorithm, graph, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I saw in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ayAEHS1-F8) video that computing the clustering coefficient of central node  of a star graph using the following algorithm is theta(n^2) and for a clique it is theta(n^3). is that correct?

```
def clustering_coefficient(G,v):
    neighbors = G[v].keys()
    if len(neighbors) == 1: return 0.0
    links = 0.0
    for w in neighbors:
        for u in neighbors:
            if u in G[w]: links += 0.5
    return 2.0*links/(len(neighbors)*(len(neighbors)-1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity depends on the density of your graph, and the efficiency of the `in` predicate.

A naive implementation on a complete graph obviously is `O(n^3)`: two nested loops and one `in` predicate, each running naively in linear time. If you keep the links in a hashmap (and not in a dense matrix representation!) then the runtime is only `O(n^2)` - for a single node. But usually, such an algorithm is applied for each node, adding another factor of `n` to it.

If your graph is not complete (and you use a more efficient `in` predicate), things get a lot faster. Assuming that every node has `sqrt(n)` neighbors, the complexity of the algorithm will be `O(sqrt(n)^2)*n` (for all nodes, that is), which is probably their `O(n^2)` result.

Assuming that every node has *exactly* two neighbors. Then the complexity can easily be brought down to `O(1) * n`. Oh, and if every node has 0 neighbors, it's even simpler.

Comment: But in python complexity of the in operator for dictionary is theta(1). so the complexity of the algorithm should be theta(n^2). why in the video it said that it is theta(n^3)?

Comment: Probably because they do it for *all* instances.

Comment: This is a sample of graph: { 'a' : { 'b' : True, 'c' : True }, 'b' : { 'a' : True, 'c' : True }, 'c' : { 'a' : True, 'b' : True }}. Doesn't if statement take theta(1) because its a dictionary? if it takes theta(1), we have theta(n^2) for loops and an if statement that takes theta(1), so it should be theta(n^2) both for star and complete graph.Am i wrong?

Comment: The *whole* function will be called `n` times, I assume.